# Httparty and file upload

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rails-api

I'm working on a rails api only application. rails 5 and ruby 2.4

My requirement is that i have make a update request which sends files to the third party api. i'm using the Postman to make requests.

Im using Httparty gem for the same.

my params are below

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"identity_kyc_doc_1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fed5d113b48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/95/z56d5kd10_sb7s82b982fpjw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180625-2016-1l5rgbn.jpeg>, @original_filename="test1.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"identity_kyc_doc_1\"; filename=\"test1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "controller"=>"simplex", "action"=>"update_kyc"} permitted: true>
```

and controller code calls a service and service action is below.

```
def update_request method, opts ={}
        headers = set_request_header

        post_data = opts#encode_options opts
        byebug
        url = @base_uri + url_path(method)
        r = self.class.put(url, { headers: headers, body: post_data }).parsed_response
        r['error'].empty? ? r['result'] : r['error']
    end
```

and im getting below error. using byebug to catch error.

```
(byebug) r = self.class.put(url, { headers: headers, body: post_data })
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `flat_map' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fed5d111b90>
```

I read somewhere in the net that httparty doesnt upload the files. What is the work around then?

i tried to use RestClient using rest-client gem. but im getting below error for the rest client gem.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1934ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
RestClient::NotFound (404 Not Found):
```

i have installed the gem also added require statement for the gem. no luck so far.

any help is appreciated.
Thanks